# signInWithPopup promise doesn't execute the .catch until I click the UI. Angular and Firebase

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, promise, firebase-authentication

I'm having a trouble with the .signInWithPopup() method provided by AngularFireAuth, you can see more here: [firebaseAuthReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#signInWithPopup)

In my auth.service.ts I've the following method.

```
 signinWithFacebook2() {
        const provider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();
        return this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(provider);
      }
```

afAuth is been injected in the auth's constructor:

```
constructor(private router: Router,
              private afAuth: AngularFireAuth){}
```

I call signinWithFacebook2() when the user click a button in my login.component.ts (click event).

```
onFacebookLogin() {
    this.authService.signinWithFacebook2()
      .then(
        (res) => {
          this.authService.getTokenId();
          this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
        }
      )
      .catch(
        (err) => {
          this.showError = true;
          // TODO fix bug. this code isn't execute until I press the button again.
        }
      );
  }
```

When the promise is resolved everything is OK, the code is executed correctly but when the reject is been accomplished the code isn't executed until I press the login button again. This is a strange behavior.Hope you have understanded my problem, if not please leve a comment.

Comment: maybe `return this.authService.signinWithFacebook2()` (no idea really :p )

Comment: I'm returning it in my auth.service.ts

Comment: not sure what that means, I'm just saying that `onFacebookLogin` doesn't return anything, is it supposed to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to force [change detection](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef) on error.

1. add import:

   ```
   import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
   ```
2. pass reference to constructor:

   ```
   constructor(private router: Router,
               private ref: ChangeDetectorRef,
               private afAuth: AngularFireAuth) {}
   ```
3. force change detection on error:

   ```
   (err) => {
     this.showError = true;
     // TODO fix bug. this code isn't execute until I press the button again.
     this.ref.detectChanges();
   )
   ```

Answer (score 0):

From the docs you provided it looks like you have to catch the errors as the second argument of the `.then()` function.

```
onFacebookLogin() {
    this.authService.signinWithFacebook2()
      .then(
        (res) => {
          this.authService.getTokenId();
          this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
        },
      (err) => {
          this.showError = true;
          // TODO fix bug. this code isn't execute until I press the button again.
        }
      );
  }
```

Comment: shouldn't make a difference if you know how Promise works :p

Comment: Yeah, never know, it may make a difference as it is different to some extent