# Angular2 ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I've read the documentation on this error, and I think I understand why the issue arises.  I'm having a problem trying to figure out an alternative architecture that would suit me.

The root component of my site (app.component) has a "loading" component on it.  It's a third party component (ngx-loading) that basically throws up a loading indicator to show the user that something is happening in the app that will take a little time.  The loading component takes a parameter that tells it whether to show up or not:

```
<ngx-loading [show]="loading" [config]="{ backdropBorderRadius: '14px' }"></ngx-loading>
```

I have a site service that holds the data for this, and my application gets the service data OnInit:

```
this.siteService.getLoading().takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe).subscribe(res => {this.loading = res})
```

The great thing about all this is that I can change the site service value from just about anywhere in my app and control whether this loading indicator pops up.  The bad thing is that now I'm seeing this ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError error.

Again, I think I understand why the error happens, but the solutions I've seen so far won't allow me to keep using this one simple component to handle all my "loading" calls.  Or am I missing something?

SiteService:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Subject }    from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

@Injectable()
export class SiteService {

  private currentRoute = new Subject<string>();
  private currentAction = new Subject<string>();

  private loading = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

  constructor() {
  }

  public menuState:string = 'in';
  toggleMenuPicker() {
    this.menuState = this.menuState === 'out' ? 'in' : 'out';
  }

  getCurrentRoute(): Observable<string> {
    return this.currentRoute.asObservable();
  }
  setCurrentRoute(route: string) {
    this.currentRoute.next(route);    
  }

  getCurrentAction(): Observable<string> {
    return this.currentAction.asObservable();
  }
  setCurrentAction(action: string) {
    this.currentAction.next(action);
  }

  getLoading(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.loading.asObservable();
  }

  setLoading(show: boolean) {
    this.loading.next(show);
  }



}
```

app.component

```
import { Component, OnDestroy, AfterContentInit } from '@angular/core';
import { trigger, state, style, transition, animate} from '@angular/animations';
import { SiteService } from './site/site.service';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/takeUntil';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  animations: [
    trigger('menuState', [
      state('in', style({
        transform: 'translate3d(-100%, 0, 0)'
      })),
      state('out', style({
        transform: 'translate3d(0, 0, 0)'
      })),
      transition('in => out', animate('200ms ease-in-out')),
      transition('out => in', animate('200ms ease-in-out'))
    ])
  ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnDestroy, AfterContentInit {
  private ngUnsubscribe: Subject<void> = new Subject<void>();

 public loading;

  constructor(public siteService: SiteService) {
  }

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    this.siteService.getLoading().takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe).subscribe(res => {this.loading = res})
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.ngUnsubscribe.next();
    this.ngUnsubscribe.complete();
  }



}
```

Comment: What are the solution that you have seen ?

Comment: I've got the same problem -> so keen to find a fix.  I'm using a custom loading screen with a DIV that displays when *ngIf parameter toggles true.

Comment: read the article [Everything you need to know about the `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` error](https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4) to learn the cause and possible fixes

Comment: You'll see that I reference that article in a response below - I've already read it.  Can you point me to the specific place in that article where the solution for this problem is laid out?  I am unable to find it.

Comment: Related issue: https://github.com/Zak-C/ngx-loading/issues/62

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush or ChangeDetectorRef.detach() to keep your single component and at the same time avoid the error.

Here is one possible solution:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'loader',
  template: `<ngx-loading [show]="loading"></ngx-loading>`
})
export class LoaderComponent {
 public loading;

 constructor(public siteService: SiteService, private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {
   this.changeDetectorRef.detach();
   this.siteService.getLoading()
                   .takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe)
                   .subscribe(res => {
                                this.loading = res;
                                this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
                    });       
  }
}
```

You can create this component an use it in the AppComponent template.

Comment: `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` will run change detection only once, ignoring any new possible model changes at the same VM turn

Comment: When we use an observable, we should use OnPush strategy combined with a call to ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges() or ChangeDetectorRef.markForCheck().

Answer (score 0):

Try to force [change detection](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef).

```
this.siteService.getLoading()
                .takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe)
                .subscribe(res => {
                  this.loading = res;
                  this.ref.detectChanges(); // <-- force change detection
                });
```

see my [similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46479930/signinwithpopup-promise-doesnt-execute-the-catch-until-i-click-the-ui-angular/46480382#46480382) for more details

Comment: I may end up doing this, but I'll be honest - it seems like a hack.  I'm reading from this: https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4.  Specifically, he says "Angular will run change detection for all child components as well".  Given that this is my top-level component, doesn't that mean I'll be slowing things down?

Comment: If you can explain to me why it's ok in this case, or why I'm being overly concerned about causing a whole new change detection cycle for the app, I'll accept.