# Creating Angular4 'Loading' Screen: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError

Tags: angular

I have created a custom loading screen where an Angular component (fullscreen DIV with SVG animation) is displayed above all other HTML.  My issue is with calling the loading screen.  At the moment, I have a boolean in a global service with an "_isLoading" variable.  When set to true, the loading screen is displayed (and vice versa), as seen below:

```
<app-loading-screen *ngIf="dataService._isLoading"></app-loading-screen>
<div id="pageWrapper">
    <app-childcomponent></app-childcomponent>
</div>
```

By default, the '_isLoading' variable is set to 'true' to display the loading screen upon initial application load.  The 'childcomponent' sets the '_isLoading' variable to 'false' once 'ngAfterViewInit' has been called, as the HTML from the child component has then loaded.  This throws an 'ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError'.  I've read the [In-Depth Blog Post](https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4) on the error, and I understand that this problem is occurring due to the child component changing a variable that the digest cycle in the parent component just checked.  What I don't know is how to get around this.  I assume others have created Loading Screens before...  What is the standard / norm for doing this?

Comment: I proposed a solution on a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46837438/angular2-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror

Comment: I've never encountered that error because I do it the other way around. I set it to false in the beginning, then flag it to true when a function is loading (for example when it's subscribing to an observable and retrieving the data), then set it back to false on completion.

Comment: read the article [Everything you need to know about the `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` error](https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4)

Comment: @AngularInDepth.com - I have read it, and I've even posted the link within my original question to Stack Overflow.  That doesn't answer my question though - I am asking what method could / should be used to get around that problem when designing a custom loading screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ngAfterViewInit` is exactly what gives you trouble. It is called **after** view has been updated with all values bound to it. So, at this moment you really should not change any data used in bindings. This also means that avoiding this error is pretty simple: all you need to do is just to wait for another change detection cycle. Simplest solution is to set timeout:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {
        dataservice._isLoading = false;
    });
}
```

But actually, I would not implement setting of this flag from two different places. The reason being is that the component starting some operation assumes responsibility for updating that operation's status. Otherwise you will end up guessing "which component just killed this request?".

Comment: I am going to give this method a shot, but you're right.  I will redesign it so the flag is toggled only within the same component.

Comment: This fixed my problem. It was because I was calling it within AfterViewInit. I've changed the way I toggle the HTML now, and only turn it on / off within the same component... No problems anymore. Thanks Alexander!